# How can I fix 'No exception of type SomeException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable'

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I have java webstart app and want to use app API for testing purposes.
So I get required (as I assumed) library from webserver and install it to maven repository.
And all is fine except custom exception which received

> No exception of type `SomeException` can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of `Throwable`

As I understand from similar topics - some jar library is missing, is there some way to know which one? or maybe there is other way to fix this? (of course I can install all jars which used for app, but there are over 90 jar's).

Comment: Let me emphasize **an exception type must be a subclass of `Throwable`**.

Comment: Where is SomeException declared?  Wherever it is, it's declared improperly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, when dev's show me an example - they don't have such error, but that project depends from other projects for which I've no access. so I assume that it should be throwable. and I'm not strong in java:(

Comment: @HotLicks `try{ some code which thows someException}catch(SomeException e){}`

Comment: Where is SomeException declared?

Comment: Google "declaration computer programming"

Comment: @HotLicks, just don't abuse me. do you mean `app.api.domain.exceptions.SomeException` ?

Comment: I mean the place where SomeException is *DECLARED*.  SomeException is a class.  Do you know how a class is declared?

Comment: Hint:  It will probably start `public class SomeException ...`

Comment: @HotLicks, I don't know where it's declared. assume if I know that I'll just get required jar and don't ask about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used JadClipse Eclipse plug-in for decompiling my jar and found that my `SomeException extends FaultInfoException` (org.codehaus.xfire.fault.FaultInfoException),and then added xfire-all dependency to my pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define a custom exception, it MUST subclass `Throwable`; but in practice you'll never subclass this directly. Subclass either of:

- `Exception` if you want to create a *checked* exception class;
- `RuntimeException` if you want to create an *unchecked* exception class.

You may also want to subclass another exception already defined by the JDK, which defines a good number of exceptions which may fit what you want to "say" with your exception.

Comment: Correct. The only way it could be a jar file problem is if SomeException sublasses SpecialEror, and in one jar file SpecialError subclasses Throwable (directly or indirectly) while in another jar file SpecialError does not subclass Throwable.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by simply inheriting the exception class with a built-in `Exception` class. Wherever you have created the exception class just add `extends Exception` there.